# Linq Index in Include

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I write program in Linq To EF4
I have in DataBase  "Items" Table that it FK to "Company" Table.
There are also "Address" Table that it FK to "Company" Table & to "City" Table.
I want to return Item include the he address & City.
But I canot write so:

```
var items = context.Items.Include("Company.Address[0].City").ToList();
```

because the Include not get "[ ]"

Comment: it helps if you include maybe the error you are receiving, more of your code, what you input is, and intended output. what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

No need for the `[0]` part:

```
var items = context.Items.Include("Company.Address.City").ToList();
```

Comment: I get erorr:

> No property or field 'City' exists in type 'TrackableCollection`1'

Comment: What are the properties/fields of Address? What is the `type` of Address?

Comment: I'm not to familiar with `TrackableCollection` but I believe the recommended class is now `ICollection`. Can you also paste the code for the `Address` class?

Comment: publicTrackableCollection<City>City
{
get
{
if(_City==null)
{
_City=newTrackableCollection<City>();
_City.CollectionChanged+=FixupCity;
}
return_City;
}
set
{
if(!ReferenceEquals(_City,value))
{
if(ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled)
{
thrownewInvalidOperationException("CannotsettheFixupChangeTrackingCollectionwhenChangeTrackingisenabled");
}
if(_City!=null)
{
_City.CollectionChanged-=FixupCity;
}
_City=value;
if(_City!=null)
{
_City.CollectionChanged+=FixupCity;
}
OnNavigationPropertyChanged("City");
}
}
}
privateTrackableCollection<City>_City;

Answer (score 0):

I get erorr:

No property or field 'Name' exists in type 'TrackableCollection`1'